# Smoothing Edgeloops

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

I´m modeling a car at the moment. As main reference i use a Blueprint. In the Prozess i offten get dents because the vertevies alonge the edgeloop are not as smoothed as the car would be (of course).
[image: Dents Rendering]
Is there a other way to make the edge loop more a uniform smooth curve to remove those darker parts in the subdiveded Mesh?
[image: Mesh Dents]
At the moment i do everything by hand. Trying to move the vertecies in a way so the darker parts are vanishing.

Comment: You could try selecting the affected faces, right-clicking  and selecting _Smooth Vertices_. You can even adjust the level from the operator panel that pops up in the bottom left afterwards. Be careful though - this may alter the underlying shape of your mesh slightly. Areas that are not selected will not be affected.

Comment: see: [How do you model panels on a car?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211345/how-do-you-model-panels-on-a-car/211358#211358)

Answer (score 0):

When using as few vertices as that and subdiving, topology is extremely important, and your topo isn't apparent-- the cage display of the subdivision hides it.

In general, a "smooth" operation or modifier can work wonders, although you often want to follow it with a shrinkwrap to a copy of your original mesh to avoid volume loss.

To deal with the explicit title, I would recommend that people install the Loop Tools addon, bundled with Blender, and use "relax" and/or "space" operation to smooth a single edge loop on its own, without respect to other edge loops.